# Nesting components in React, props not passing to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm creating a list with React components, and am working on the list container and reusable list-item components. The parent most component passes information to middle component, but the child-most component does not have `props` values.

What am I doing wrong? No console errors.
middle component:

```
const VideoList = (props) => {
  const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
    return (
      // want to render list-item component
      <li key={video.etag}>{video.snippet.title}</li>
    )
  });
  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
    {videoItems}
      <ListItem
        videos={ videoItems }
      />
    </ul>
  )
}
```

a console log in child-most component shows no props

Comment: Im a little confused by your code. Are you meaning to render both `videoItems `  and an element called `<ListItem/>` that takes `videoItems` as props? also, what element do you mean by child-most?

Answer (score 5):

I think it will be better if you pass `props` directly into the children component. Try this:

```
const VideoList = (props) => {
  const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
    return (
      // want to render list-item component
      <ListItem key={video.etag} video={video} />
    )
  });
  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
      {videoItems}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Inside your children component, you can display what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the property to the child-most component using the 'this' keyword.

```
    <ListItem videos={this.videoItems}/>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, `VideoList` is a stateless functional component and hence there is **no** `this`.

Comment: ohh! Right, Thanks !

Comment: Thanks! that's very helpful